# Views pager in a panel page

Tags: views, panels

I created a view to show a nodes image field (unlimited values) and placed that views block into a panel page region. For some reason the pager doesn't show up. I googled around but cant see any others having these issues. All the associated images are shown on the page instead of the 6 i set up in views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just after posting here i went back to the problem. Turns out i only had to check off the "Display all values in the same row" in the "Multiple field settings" section of the field in the view. Pager showed up now.